# Fazer delay em Java

Tags: java

É possível fazer um delay em Java? 
Como por exemplo,eu tenho duas mensagens e quero que a segunda apareça apenas alguns segundos depois,é possível?

Comment: Além do `Thread.sleep()` é possível usar a `enum` `java.uti.concurrent.TimeUnit`, ela aumenta a legibilidade do código, por exemplo um delay de 5 minutos com `Thread.sleep()` fica `Thread.sleep(300000)`, já com `TimeUnit` fica `TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(5)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente usar Thread.sleep();

```
package com.journaldev.threads;

public class ThreadSleep {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // pausa de 2 segundos
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("Sleep time in ms = "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-start));

    }

}
```